# Fill with most probable values R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 2 columns:

```r
a<-c(1, 3, 4, 6, 8.7, 9, 10, 12, 19.3, 20)
b<-c(10, 30, 40, 60, 87, 90, 100, 120, 190, 200)
df<-data.frame(a=a, b=b)
> df
      a   b
1   1.0  10
2   3.0  30
3   4.0  40
4   6.0  60
5   8.7  87
6   9.0  90
7  10.0 100
8  12.0 120
9  19.3 190
10 20.0 200
```

This will give this plot:

[image]

My aim is first, to have values in a column from 1 to 20, and for each value b should be calculated as the most probable value (to get the approximate plot with exactly 20 values of b in all 20 classes of a)

**Expected values:**

```r
a<-c(1:20)
b<-c(100,110,120,130,92,60,59,58,44,103,....)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want linear interpolation?

Comment: Yes, I think that's it linear interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for linear interpolation. The `approx` function can be used for this:

```r
as.data.frame(approx(df$a, df$b, xout = c(1:20)))
#    x        y
#1   1  10.0000
#2   2  20.0000
#3   3  30.0000
#4   4  40.0000
#5   5  50.0000
#6   6  60.0000
#7   7  70.0000
#8   8  80.0000
#9   9  90.0000
#10 10 100.0000
#11 11 110.0000
#12 12 120.0000
#13 13 129.5890
#14 14 139.1781
#15 15 148.7671
#16 16 158.3562
#17 17 167.9452
#18 18 177.5342
#19 19 187.1233
#20 20 200.0000
```

Comment: In my real data some values of y are NA, I dont know why?
I think because in my real data, I dont have boundaries

Comment: Possibly your data is out of range. if x goes up to 20, but you want to predict a value for xout of 25, linear interpolation doesn't make sense. There are no two values between which to interpolate

Comment: in fact all my a colum values are between 1 and 20, however in some df, It does not start from 1, it might start from 5, and in some it might not end with 20 but with 15

Comment: If your data is out of range you want to extrapolate. You could try `approxExtrap` from the `Hmisc` package. `approxExtrap(df$a, df$b, xout = c(25))`